# Setting Proxy URL with unicode characters using InternetSetOption function

Tags: c, winapi, character-encoding, special-characters, wininet

I'm stuck in a problem for quite a while.

The Windows user account name contains some of these characters (Ö, Ü, Ä). Edit: Even chinese characters. So basically the characters which aren't covered in ASCII.
I have a proxy pac file stored in %appdata%\MyAppFolder. - This path when expanded contains some special characters like the ones mentioned above.

I have to set this path in

> IE->InternetOptions->Connections->LAN settings->Use automatic configuration script

```
This translates to:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\AutoConfigURL in the registry.
```

Code Excerpt:

```
wchar_t wzsPath[MAX_PATH];
wchar_t wszProxyUrl[INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH];
SHGetFolderPath ( NULL, CSIDL_APPDATA | CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE, NULL, 0, wszPath );

// Construct Pac file path. – %appdata%\MyAppFolder\redirect.pac
StringCbPrintf (wszProxyUrl, sizeof(wszProxyUrl), 
        L"file://%s\\MyAppFolder\\redirect.pac", wszPath );

INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST *optionList = 0;
optionList->pOptions[INDEX].Value.pszValue = wszPath;

InternetSetOption ( NULL, INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION,
        optionList, sizeof(INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST) );
```

The problem is that the path set by InternetSetOption is incorrect in the Registry location.

The string "TestÖ" for example is set as "TestÃ–" in the Registry. IE9 sets the text right in the browser, but without any help. IE10 sets junk value as in the registry.
This is causing the disruption of Network access.

Comment: ASCII characters have values in the range 0 to 127 inclusive. Clearly 153, 154 and 142 are not part of ASCII. As it stands your question is not a question because the facts are all wrong. What's more you've not given us any code so that we can actually work out where these values are coming from.

Comment: Thanks David. I was stumped by [link](http://www.asciitable.com/) Extended ASCII section. While printing on console expects this(extended ascii value), printing the characters in a MessageBox/Debug String reads the html code page value.

Comment: I will add some meaningful code excerpt soon.

Comment: Windows doesn't use that particular extended ascii table. The native Windows encoding is UTF-16 Unicode. Call the Unicode versions of the Windows API and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

`InternetSetOption` is a fairly normal Win32 function. It is available in two flavours, the ANSI and Unicode versions. The need for these different versions comes from the fact that Windows 95/98/ME did not support Unicode and only had support for 8 bit encodings. Since you can safely ignore those ancient versions of Windows, you can use the Unicode versions of the Win32 API.

In your case this means that you make sure that you compile your application to target Unicode. This will make sure that `InternetSetOption` is mapped to `InternetSetOptionW`, the Unicode version which uses the UTF-16 encoding.

Your character arrays should use the Windows 16 bit character type `wchar_t` as the base character type. You must not use `char` because that is 8 bit.

I'm not sure that this change will resolve your actual problem because the question is unclear and lacking in detail. However, the above advice is what you need to do to be able to properly support international characters in your program.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I was mislead by these extended ascii values.

The problem actually is with all the charcaters with value > 127.
Here is the code excerpt.

`
SHGetFolderPath ( NULL, CSIDL_APPDATA | CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE, NULL, 0, wszPath );

INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST *optionList = 0;

optionList->pOptions[INDEX].Value.pszValue = wszPath;

InternetSetOption ( NULL, INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION, optionList, sizeof(INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST) );
`

Comment: I think I've answered your original question as well as is reasonably possible. What more do you need?

Comment: Yes. Your reply helped clear my wrong leads.
Have edited my Question quite a bit. Hopefully it is clearer.

Comment: `optionList` is a null pointer. You don't ever point it at a valid object. You also have no error checking in your code. You need to check return values for every API call you make.

Comment: I'm allocating memory to optionList.
There is a call to an Allocation function which does the job. I'm also checking all the return values of all the APIs. No error anywhere.
Also did a decimal value check on every character passed to the InternetSetOption function. Everything is precise.

Comment: An alternative  manual write to registry ....
HKEY hKey;
long status1 = RegOpenKeyEx(
      HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
      L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings",
      0,
      KEY_ALL_ACCESS,
      &hKey
     );

if (status1 == 0) {
 status1 = RegSetValueEx(hKey, L"AutoConfigURL", 0, REG_SZ, (PBYTE)winProxy->s_proxyUrl, sizeof(winProxy->s_proxyUrl));
 RegCloseKey(hKey);
}

works fine allowing network access.

Comment: Oh figured something weird just now. I wrote a special character in **IE->InternetOptions->Connections->LAN settings->Use automatic configuration script** ... The characters are not reflecting properly under **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\AutoConfigURL**.